# Salesforce Flow running fine in debug, but when executing in sandbox nothing is happening

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-flow

Apologies in advance for my lack in SF verbiage I am currently trying to learn!

I currently have 2 different asset record types, Network equipment and Sim Card. In the Networking equipment record I have a lookup field named Sim Card ID which links the Sim Card record to the Networking equipment record for tracking purposes. In both records there is an Account lookup field . I want to link the Account field to both of the record types so that when I add a new Sim Card to the Networking Equipment the Sim card account will update automatically according to the Networking Equipment Account. I am currently using a record triggered flow setup below,[Outline of my current flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnTZj.png)

Thought process,

1. Whenever the network equipment has the Sim Card ID field changed then trigger flow start.

[Start Condition Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTF6m.png)

2. I will then create an assignment element. This will create the GetHotspotLocation which will take the record Account ID. Next the GEtSimCardRecordID variable will be assigned the Sim Card Record ID.

[Variable Assignment Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fcYv.png)

3. Finally I will update the Sim Card record type with the new Account ID. This is done by filtering record types by the GetSimCardRecordID variable from the assignment element. Then the AccountID will be assigned the GetHotSpotLocation.

[Update Records Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaifE.png)

I ran debug and all seemed to work out properly. However after activation and testing in the sandbox the flow is not updating the account field. I know that debug runs in sort of a vacuum. So I looked at the dev console after updating the Networking Equipment record type with a new Sim Card. I saw that the flow ran and no other flow was acting upon the Record. I am unsure of where to look to make the correction.

Comment: Stackoverflow is more for "real" code problems. Click-click-config questions may have more luck at dedicated https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/, more admins over there. I don't like you assigning a "normal" id like account id to the special recordtypeid field? Double check the step in https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaifE.png

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.